# JS text not appearing on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

New to programming and am stumped as to why text won't appear on my canvas.

HTML:

```
    <div id="gameWindow">
        <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="854" height="480"></canvas>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



    ctx.font = "32px Verdana";
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillText("Hello World", 400, 400);
}
```

CSS:

```
#gameCanvas {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    align-self: center;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `init` method

```js
function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "32px Verdana";
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fillText("Hello World", 400, 400);
}
init() //Changed here
```

```css
#gameCanvas {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  align-self: center;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameWindow">
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="854" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was missing that step along with realizing that the script was being called before the HTML ran! '